# apache wsgi route url to wordpress

Tags: php, apache, mod-wsgi

Currently my domain foo.com is handled by the wsgi script, but I require urls under foo.com/articles* to map to some WordPress php pages stored in the `public_html` folder. This is my feeble attempt -

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/foo/property_buyer/buyer.wsgi
WSGIDaemonProcess foo processes=7 threads=1 display-name=%{GROUP}
WSGIProcessGroup foo
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

Alias /articles /home/foo/public_html/articles/
Alias /media/ /home/foo/static/

<Directory /home/foo/static>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I've got the following error though -

```
[Wed May 16 00:22:03 2012] [error] [client 121.6.147.148] SoftException in Application.cpp:422: Mismatch between target UID (506) and UID (503) of file "/home/property/public_html/articles/index.php"
    [Wed May 16 00:22:03 2012] [error] [client 121.6.147.148] Premature end of script headers: index.php
```

Am I doing the correct way, or does anyone knows what does the error means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically it should be:

```
Alias /articles/ /home/foo/public_html/articles/
```

but before it even gets to that, seems your system is setup to use suexec or something for PHP and the file system permissions of files don't match what was expected. So, look at correcting the file system permissions on directories/files to what it is expecting.

Comment: thanks @graham, your prompt support is as helpful as your product itself. Will try it out.